# Perl LWP Find links in page that contain a specific word

Tags: match, lwp

I am really stuck.
I am using LWP.
I desire to push specific links from an HTML document into an array.
But:

```
while ($edocument =~ m/href\s*=\s*"([^"\s]+)"/gi) {
#dostuff
}
```

Will process all the links.
I just want the links that have the word 'test' in the url.

I have tried all kinds of combinations like. (too many attempts to list)

```
  while ($edocument =~ m/href\s*=\s*"([^"\s*test*]+)"/gi) {
```

I have been reading and reading and I really need a clue for this embarrassing situation.

Can someone help?

In addition, I only need ONE match of the word test per `$edocument` as well. Kind of like `last` I guess in a loop.

Also tried variations of

`@links = $edocument =~ m/<a[^>]+href\s*=\s*["']?([^"'> ]+)/ig;`

Then ran @links through a unique sub. But still, just need links with the word 'test'.

Comment: I am trying to figure this out. I know what \s and * but, why would a match occur? I read the regex like href[space]*=[space]*"[space]*  I have tried to find an explanation of this regex everywhere so I can have enough of a clue to expand on it myself.

Comment: Hours later and my attempts are still failing. Taking a break. Hopefully someone will chime in here soon and help. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the following regexp:

```
while ($edocument =~ m/href\s*=\s*"([^"\s]+test[^"\s]+)"/gi) { #dostuff }
```

This regexp only matches urls with substring test in it.

Comment: Thank you.. I am trying.. Additionally, if I wanted to do a 10 digit number check, would this work? m/href\s*=\s*"([^"\s]+[0-9a-z]{10}[^"\s]+)"/gi)

Comment: You have to remove the "a-z" part from your regexp if you only want to match 10 digit numbers. The following regexp should do the trick to select only urls with 10 digit numbers in it: m/href\s*=\s*"([^"\s]+\d{10}[^"\s]+)"/gi)